# How to recognize what unit testing framework is used in a project in Visual Studio, .NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, automated-tests, visual-studio-2019

I am working with a Visual Studio C# project and I need to know what unit testing framework is it using, but there is no one to ask about it.

How could I check it?

Comment: look at what references the test project has?

Comment: @MarcGravell, thank you for your attention. With the help of your comment I was able to determine that the `xunit` is used.

Comment: @MarcGravell, should I remove the post?

Comment: I have no strong opinion on that

Comment: @MarcGravell, ok. So, since you helped me, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most reliable thing here would be to look at the project references that the test project has (either in the IDE by expanding "References" in the solution explorer, or by looking at the csproj directly). You will probably find something like xunit, nunit, mstest, or something else indicative of what you're using.

Note that this will often be **in addition to** `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, which is related to just making it testable; for example, I have an xunit project that includes:

```xml
    <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.3.0" />
```

The bottom two are for integration purposes; the top one is the actual test framework reference.

Comment: Note that this is only relevant for newer csproj structure and .NET Core.

Comment: @Euphoric, in my case .NET Framework is used, but not .NET Core and the answer is still relevant for me.

Comment: @Euphoric references exist either way; and emphasis: the new csproj format isn't just for .NET Core - you can target .NET Framework with it

Comment: True, sorry for confusion. Sure, those packages work on anything .NET Standard. But it is still true those PackageReferences will only be in newer csproj structure. Older structure still use packages.xml

Comment: @Euphoric you're right about packages.xml in the older format - but: no, the new csproj is not just netstandard - out of the box you can target regular honest .NET Framework down to .NET 4.0; with a two line tweak (aka MSBuild.Sdk.Extras) you can target down to .NET 2.0

Comment: @MarcGravell That is what I said. I might not be clear there.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things to pay attention to.

First is the testing framework used in the code. Most common are nUnit, xUnit and MSTest. This is easily checked by looking at references of the project, or installed NuGet packages.

But, Visual Studio needs to be able to discover and run those tests. For that, each testing framework usually has an adapter that is installed either as visual studio plugin (usually older version) or as a reference or a NuGet package. For nUnit, that would be [NUnit3TestAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit3TestAdapter/) or for xUnit [Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.runner.visualstudio/).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about spending some seconds you should use the official way of determining if a csproj file contains tests:

```
dotnet test --list-tests <project.csproj>
```

Related documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test

This will list all the tests in that project without executing them.